# Create Table Variable (or Temp Table) from an existing Table but with an Extra Column

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table variable or temporary table, using data from another table but with an extra column.

I know I could use SELECT INTO as follows

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempTable
FROM Existing_Table
WHERE Section = 2
```

and then use

```
ALTER TABLE #TempTable ADD New_Column
```

And finally

```
DROP #TempTable
```

I will then be looping through each row with a dynamically called stored procedure to place values in the new column. Its not a big table.

Is that the best way? My understanding is that I cannot use the above with a table variable.

Thanks

Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its simpler

```
SELECT *, cast('hbkkj' as nvarchar(100)) as New_Column
INTO #TempTable
FROM Existing_Table
WHERE Section = 2
```